# What would be the induction hypothesis in my proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I proved that any amount greater than 24 cents can be obtained by a combination of 5 cents and 7 cents using strong induction. First I proved the following base cases:

$$24=2(5)+2(7)$$
$$25=5(5)$$
$$26=5+3(7)$$
$$27=4(5)+7$$
$$28=4(7)$$

Then for my induction step, I used the fact that every number n greater than 24 can be written in one of the following forms: 
$$24+5k$$
$$25+5k$$
$$26+5k$$
$$27+5k$$
$$28+5k$$

I then substitued 24, 25, 26, 27 and 28 by the terms in the base cases to show that in each case, n could be written as a combination of 5 cents and 7 cents.

However, I used the base cases directly in the inductive step, I did not use any induction hypothesis. Is an induction hypothesis really needed in this case, or can we do without one? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use induction here. After your observation the statement is proven.

Comment: If you have proved your claim $24+5k$ etc. your proof is done. The "induction" would be to assume $24+5k$ to be true for $k$, and then substitute for $n = k+1$. Because your claim is true for all $n \in \mathbb N$, the proof is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used induction implicitly, when asserting that any number greater than $24$ can be written as $x+5k$, with $24\le x\le 28$.

Instead your (strong) induction hypothesis should be: *let $n>28$ and assume every integer $k$ with $24\le k<n$ can be obtained with $5$ and $7$ cents.*

Then $24\le n-5<n$ so, $n-5=5a+7b$ and therefore $n=5(a+1)+7b$.